# Android Recycler view Video Preloading / Precaching in Xamarin using Exoplayer

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, exoplayer

What I Want : When scroll to a video in recyclerview or when the video post is visible it will start playing the video instantly from the cached source. When i scrolled down it will again stop playing the video and same thing will happen for the next video in the recyclerview.

What I did : I Made a CacheVideo function and called it in the PostAdapter in OnBindViewHolder and Passed the video URI using VideCache.CacheVideosFiles(url).

I used Exoplayer for Video Playback in a Recycler view. Recylerview contains Video Posts along with other posts.
I used a VideoCache Class like this -
`VideoCache.cs` -

```
namespace Example.Helpers.CacheLoaders
{
    public class VideoCache
    {
        private CacheDataSourceFactory CacheDataSourceFactory;
        private static SimpleCache Cache;
        private static readonly DefaultBandwidthMeter BandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        private DefaultDataSourceFactory DefaultDataSourceFac;
        private Context MainContext;
        public void CacheVideosFiles(Uri url)
        {
            try
            {
                MainContext = Application.Context;
                Cache ??= new SimpleCache(MainContext.CacheDir, new NoOpCacheEvictor());

                CacheDataSourceFactory ??= new CacheDataSourceFactory(Cache, DefaultDataSourceFac);

                var dataSpec = new DataSpec(url, 0, 1000 * 1024, null); //0, 1000 * 1024, null
                var counters = new CacheUtil.CachingCounters();

                CacheUtil.GetCached(dataSpec, Cache, counters);

                if (counters.ContentLength == counters.TotalCachedBytes())
                {

                }
                else if (counters.TotalCachedBytes() == 0)
                {
                    // not cached at all
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var cacheDataSource = new CacheDataSource(Cache, CacheDataSourceFactory.CreateDataSource());
                            CacheUtil.Cache(dataSpec, Cache, cacheDataSource, counters, new AtomicBoolean());
                            double downloadPercentage = (counters.TotalCachedBytes() * 100d) / counters.ContentLength;
                            Console.WriteLine(downloadPercentage);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // just few mb cached
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used this class to cache the video. I used this class in
`OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)`

```
 switch (itemViewType)
                { .....
                    case (int)PostModelType.VideoPost:
                        {
if (!(viewHolder is AdapterHolders.PostVideoSectionViewHolder holder))
                                return;

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PostData.PostFileThumb))
                                FullGlideRequestBuilder.Load(item.PostData.PostFileThumb).Into(holder.VideoImage);
                            else
                                FullGlideRequestBuilder.Load(item.PostData.PostFileFull).Into(holder.VideoImage);

                            
                            
                           Android.Net.Uri VideoUrl = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(item.PostData.PostFileFull);
                           videoCache.CacheVideosFiles(VideoUrl);
                           

                            break;
}
}...
```

And now in my custom RecyclerView

```
 private void PlayVideo(bool isEndOfList)
        {
 Context context = Application.Context;
                Cache ??= new SimpleCache(context.CacheDir, new NoOpCacheEvictor());

                var videoSource = GetMediaSourceFromUrl(VideoUrl, "normal");

                var dataSpec = new DataSpec(VideoUrl); //0, 1000 * 1024, null

                if (Cache == null)
                    videoCache.CacheVideosFiles(VideoUrl);
                

                CacheDataSourceFactory ??= new CacheDataSourceFactory(Cache, DefaultDataSourceFac);

                var counters = new CacheUtil.CachingCounters();

                CacheUtil.GetCached(dataSpec, Cache, counters);
                if (counters.ContentLength == counters.TotalCachedBytes())
                {
                    videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(CacheDataSourceFactory).CreateMediaSource(VideoUrl);
                }
                else if (counters.TotalCachedBytes() == 0)
                {
                    videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(CacheDataSourceFactory).CreateMediaSource(VideoUrl);
                    // not cached at all
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var cacheDataSource = new CacheDataSource(Cache, CacheDataSourceFactory.CreateDataSource());
                            CacheUtil.Cache(dataSpec, Cache, cacheDataSource, counters, new AtomicBoolean());
                            double downloadPercentage = (counters.TotalCachedBytes() * 100d) / counters.ContentLength;
                            Console.WriteLine(downloadPercentage);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // partially cached
                    videoSource ??= new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(CacheDataSourceFactory).CreateMediaSource(VideoUrl);
                }

                VideoPlayer.Prepare(videoSource);
                VideoPlayer.AddListener(lis);
                VideoPlayer.PlayWhenReady = true;
            }
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom `LinearLayoutManager`, then override the `OnAttachedToWindow`, add `AddOnChildAttachStateChangeListener` for your recycleView. create a `MyOnChildAttachStateChangeListener` for `AddOnChildAttachStateChangeListener`. `MyOnChildAttachStateChangeListener` have two method. `OnChildViewAttachedToWindow` and `OnChildViewDetachedFromWindow`, `OnChildViewAttachedToWindow` will be executed the Video is showing in the screen, `OnChildViewDetachedFromWindow` will be executed the video is disappear in the screen.

Comment: Like this class:https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/ViewPagerLayoutManager